# Kubuntu 22.04 Wayland odd refresh rate

Tags: kubuntu, display, wayland, compositing, framerate

I'm trying to run Kubuntu 22.04.1 with wayland but I have this annoying issue I can't figure out. When in the desktop with no windows open everything is running smooth but as soon as something else is displayed on screen, there is this small lag or delay with the mouse and animations. The only way I can describe it is as if the framerate dropped. I have tried changing the compositor settings, scaling settings, animation speed and nothing seems to work. I also connect a second monitor and the secondary display runs better ad the same refresh rate (60hz) and flawless at 120hz.

This only happens on Wayland as x11 doesn't have this problem. I also run Fedora 36 on Virtual Box with the same settings and it works great from the VM. Any ideas?

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.25.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.98.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-52-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz/3.9Ghz
Memory: 7.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
Manufacturer: HP
Product Name: HP EliteBook x360 1030 G4

Edit: If anybody else faces the issue, it turned out to be theming. I reverted all theming back to breeze and everything was running smoothly again. The problem happened when changing application style or window decoration.

Edit2: Playing around a bit more, I went to Settings > Workspace behavior > desktop effects and enabled "Show FPS". I noticed with themes the FPS's went from 120 to 80fps. The culprit here turned out to be the "Blur" effect. Turning it off got the FPS back to 120. There was still framedrops which turned out to be "Kvantum". Changing the application style from Kvantum to Breeze and disabling blur allowed to theme under wayland at a more stable FPS (only seeing minor drops when maximizing and minimizing probably due to Aurorae theme with blur)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It turned out to be theming causing the issue. I wasn't trying to report a bug, more to see if anybody know if there is a tweak or something for the lag. I would appreciate a more complete reply and directions to where to file this bug as it is not present in Fedora.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I believe the nature of KDE encourages tweaking so theming is something anybody would want to do in KDE. Wayland has some settings and features that are not in X11, I thought maybe I was missing a vsync setting or something that changed in Wayland, that someone had knowledge of. In another forum for example someone suggested changing Compositor settings, and another person that had a similar issue managed to decrease the lag. Ubuntu ships wayland by default now so sorry for trying to see if anybody had a similar issue and knew how to fix it.